# How to allow users to moderate their own forum threads?

Tags: users, nodes

In Drupal 6 forum, I want to give certain thread initiators the permission to edit/delete the thread posts that they find unsuitable, but only on their own threads. How can I do so? Thanks

Comment: Are you just using the core Forum module or are you using Advanced Forums?

Comment: I'm using Advanced Forum.